# Android statusBarColor vs colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat

> These two fields have same affect but **statusBarColor** has **higher
>   precedence** in theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

in the above code statusBar has **black** color but in below code statusBar has **white** color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**What is main deference in AppCompat Theme?**

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar

Answer (score 5):

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

> To set a custom color for the status bar, use the android:statusBarColor attribute when you extend the material theme. By default, android:statusBarColor inherits the value of android:colorPrimaryDark.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Google updated that link and the referenced quote is no longer on that page; I found a reference to it on a github archive of the docs, but the current docs only seem to suggest using colorPrimaryDark - no idea why.

Comment: @Simon yes colorPrimaryDark is the way to go now

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between statusBarColor and colorPrimaryDark is:

- **statusBarColor:** Sets the color for the status bar (and just that)
- **colorPrimaryDark:** Sets the color for the status bar and contextual app bars.

This is why **statusBarColor** takes precedence over **colorPrimaryDark** for the status bar when both have different colors.